# Are there any beginner Craft tutorials?

Tags: resources

I've been building sites with ModX Revolution for about 4 months but I've heard great things about Craft. I downloaded and installed it and the interface looks great.

To perform a detailed evaluation, I need to dive in and start building a basic site. But I don't know where to start. I found the mijingo tutorials but I have to pay $39.00 then mijingo tells me that I can only get so far with a free Craft license. To get the full experience, I need to buy at least a client license.

Are there any beginner tutorials for Craft that are free or at least don't require me to commit to the client Craft license?

Thanks.

Comment: Due to the nature of this question, it's been converted into a community wiki. _"Questions should be manually converted to community wiki when they are marginal fits or 'list of X' questions that contain enough value to avoid deletion."_

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you run Craft from a non-public domain, you actually have the option to switch between Craft Personal, Craft Client, and Craft Pro for free, forever.

You can start with using the "[On The Rocks](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ontherocks)" example website.

> “What is a non-public domain", you ask? We consider any domain that ends with `.dev`, `.local`, or any other unofficial/nonregistrable TLD, to be non-public, as well as other special cases such as `localhost` and IP addresses. You can view the full list of things we check in [this help article](https://craftcms.com/support/license-enforcement#how-do-we-determine-craft-is-running-on-a-public-domain).
>
> *From https://pixelandtonic.com/blog/test-craft-client-pro-from-any-non-public-domain*

Comment: **UPDATE:** It's now possible to try Craft Pro from _any_ non-public domain: http://pixelandtonic.com/blog/test-craft-client-pro-from-any-non-public-domain

Answer (score 17):

**Testing all Craft versions:**

> If you would like to try out Craft Client or Craft Pro before buying,
>   you can do so by running your site from the host name craft.dev.
>   Subdomains work as well, e.g. site1.craft.dev.

See: [How can I try Craft Client or Craft Pro before buying?](http://buildwithcraft.com/help/try-craft-client-pro)

**Tutorials:**

- [Mijingo's Learning
  Craft](https://mijingo.com/products/screencasts/craft-cms-tutorial/) - Most comprehensive tutorial
- [Basic of templating in Craft](http://withchief.com/blog/basics-of-templating-in-craft)
- [Twig Primer](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/twig-primer)
- [Twig for Designers](https://github.com/brandonkelly/TwigForDesigners) - A work-in-progress book from Brandon Kelly
- [Templating in EE vs. Craft](https://gist.github.com/brandonkelly/8584132)

**Examples:**

P&T has demo files for two sites on github, which you can install locally:

- [HappyLager](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/HappyLager)
- [On the Rocks](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ontherocks)

**Resources:**

- [Craft Cookbook](http://craftcookbook.net/) - Code Snippets
- [Straight up Craft](http://straightupcraft.com/) - Articles / Link lists / Tweets / Plugin List

Comment: Wow, that was quick. Thanks for the answer. I have it set up on my local MAMP install as craft.dev.

Comment: Is there just a complete guide for Craft plugin developers? Official documentation explains only how to work with mouse in CP and gives only few words for developers. When I start to code I stuck at every simple thing. Simple creation of new Element programmatically turns into a real quest, because it's absolutely not clear what methods should I use, what parameters etc... And don't even think to try to make complex relational fields programmatically. That's where the nightmare begins. Craft really needs a clear guide like it's parent Yii has. Recipes can't replace a complete guide.

Comment: Update: Up and Running with Craft (the newest version of Mijingo's Learning Craft) is now free for everyone at CraftQuest.io. https://craftquest.io/courses/craft-cms-3-tutorials