# Question about breadcrumb links

Tags: navigation

I am using Craft only for the blog section of my HTML site. I have integrated my existing breadcrumbs to the blog, but there is a problem.

When I am on the home page of the blog, the word "Blog" in the breadcrumb is linked, and I would rather it **not** be linked.

I would like the word "Blog" in the breadcrumb to be a link only after going to an article on the blog. Please see attached.

[image: Screen shot comparing the Home page of the blog and an Article page]

The code I am using right now is

```
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
        <li><a href="/index.html">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="{{ siteUrl }}">Blog</a></li>
            {% for crumb in entry.getAncestors() %}
                <li>{{ crumb.getLink() }}</li>
            {% endfor %}
            <li>{{ entry.title() }}</li>
    </ol>
```

I am new to Craft - thanks for your help!

Comment: Just to be clear... is the section that `entry` lives in a structured section?

Comment: ...ummm I don't think it's structured. I am working off the the sample templates included with Craft.

Answer (score 2):

A conditional that keys off the presence of the second segment to determine what to show for the "Blog" link/copy will work.

```
{% set seg2 = "" %}
{% set seg2 = craft.request.getSegment(2) %}

<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
    <li>
        {% if seg2 == "" %}
            Blog
        {% else %}
            <a href="{{ siteUrl }}">Blog</a>
        {% endif %}
    </li>
    {% for crumb in entry.getAncestors() %}
        <li>{{ crumb.getLink() }}</li>
    {% endfor %}
    <li>{{ entry.title() }}</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Worked like a charm ... I am still getting a "/" after "Blog" on the Home page of the Blog but I can live with that. TY again.

Comment: Is the "/" coming from your CSS? It's not in the code that you posted.

Comment: I think it's a bootstrap style. If you 'inspect element' `::before` is shown and I think that is where the slashes are coming from.

Comment: @SteveVH If so, you can wrap the "Blog" text within the conditional in a span, e.g. ```<span class="nolink">Blog</span>```, and hide the slash in your CSS like so: ```.nolink:before { display: none; }```

Answer (score 2):

First, if your Blog section type is a Channel and not a Structure, then `{% for crumb in entry.getAncestors() %}` won't return anything. Your entry needs to be in a structure have any ancestors.

Here's a rundown of Craft's section types:

http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/sections-and-entries

This is really going to depend on how you have your templates and sections are setup, but here's how a basic setup for a Blog channel might work.

Let's say you have a **Blog** section that's a **Channel** section type. In your `craft/templates` folder, you have the following folders:

```
blog/
blog/index.html
blog/_entry.html
```

In the settings for the Blog section, you have...

**Entry URL Format:** `blog/{slug}`

**Entry Template:** `blog/_entry`

If you're on an entry page like `example.com/blog/what-makes-a-good-logo-design`, Craft will route to the `blog/_entry.html` template. In that file your breadcrumb could be just this:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="{{ siteUrl }}">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="/blog">Blog</a></li>
    <li>{{ entry.title }}</li>
</ol>
```

If you go to `example.com/blog`, Craft will route to the `blog/index.html` template. In that file, you can have a separate breadcrumb like this:

```
<ol class="breadcrumb">
    <li><a href="{{ siteUrl }}">Home</a></li>
    <li>Blog</li>
</ol>
```

Comment: Thanks for the further clarification. I'm new to Craft and still trying to understand all of it!

Comment: OK so I just had that "aha" moment - I really didn't understand until now about the "block - endblock" concept and how you can replace different sections with new stuff. 

I mentioned to Craft how they really need to have a primer for the non-developer/designer that gives a step-by-step on how to develop a basic Craft site, like Mike Boyink's and Ryan Irelan's [excellent] books for EE. :)

Comment: There's a good list of beginner resources on this question "Are there any beginner Craft tutorials?": http://craftcms.stackexchange.com/a/1826/273